# *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module! when installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, radeon, usb-installation, compaq

I'm trying to revive this old computer with windows 8.1 installed running very very slow. But when booting from usb, I got "blank" screen with just 1 color, and the color go changing. If I try to boot with safe graphics, I just got a glimpse of the wallpaper then this:
[image]

What I'm missing?

EDIT: starting ubuntu in safe graphics gives me this error:

```
[drm:radeon_module_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

EDIT2: I was able to try-live ubuntu 20.04.1 y 18.04.6 but the colored blank screen appears after  a few minutes...

Comment: Did you verify the ISO as being valid first?  then did you validate the write to ISO? (ie. *as you can't using that box; I'd use a different box to perform that validation*).  Also you weren't specific as to which 20.04 ISO you booted/tried, but given ISOs exist with GA kernel stack (5.4), 5.8, 5.11 & 5.13 there are ISOs providing 4+ kernel stacks (*I'm ignoring OEM*) and if it's related to '*drivers*' (ie. kernel modules) you've a number of choices that may suit your hardware better, but I'd return to validation of ISO & media write first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I downloaded the iso from ubuntu oficial site, SO i don't have any other info, I'll check everything you mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I've never minded this, I guess is never late to learn

Comment: @guiverc Hi again, I added new info in the question, If you have any insights I'll appreciate them. In googling now in my end.

Comment: If you couldn't even run a live Ubuntu (I would try last LTS, 22.04) then maybe is a hardware issue. Did you try [removing `nomodeset`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420298/209677) from kernel parameters?

Comment: I tried both. Every works just fine. But after a few minutes I got the screen in the picture or this: https://yadi.sk/i/ch1JYowvxwdtpg